# How to hold a button in touch screen

Tags: c#, button, touchscreen

I wrote a program that controls PTZ camera through network,
when i "MouseDown" a button it sends a command to move and when i "MouseUp" a button it sends a command to stop the movement.
when i try to use it with a touch screen it does't work well, it acts like a click even when i hold the button.
How can i make it work like with a mouse?

```
    private void PTZp6_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient("192.168.5.205", 52381);
        Byte[] sendBytes = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xff, 0x81, 0x01, 0x04, 0x3f, 0x02, 0x05, 0xFF };
        try
        {
            udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void PTZp6_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        byte[] data = BitConverter.GetBytes(Speed.Value);
        UdpClient udpClient = new UdpClient("192.168.5.205", 52381);
        Byte[] sendBytes = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x09, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0xff, 0x81, 0x01, 0x06, 0x01, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0x03, 0xFF };
        try
        {
            udpClient.Send(sendBytes, sendBytes.Length);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this WinForms or WPF? Also, `Console.WriteLine` won't work in a GUI application, don't you want to use `Debug.WriteLine` instead?

Comment: Tis is a form in c#